# Svelte: Reactive computed variable bind to input

Tags: input, bind, svelte, reactive

I have a reactive computed variable that is dependant to svelte store and gets initialized by making an API call when the page refreshes.
I want to bind this value to an input. With this code my input doesn't work (nothing can be typed in it)

Please see [this REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/2d601f9ae52641c994b3a25551ce270d?version=3.48.0) and here is the code:
This is `App.svelte`

```
    <script>
    import {loggedInUserProfile} from './store.js'  
    import { onMount } from 'svelte'
    import {update} from './util.js'
    
    let loggedInUserInfo
  loggedInUserProfile.subscribe((value) => (loggedInUserInfo = value))
    
    onMount(() => {
    console.log('App onMount called')
    update()        
  })
    
    const capitalizeFirstLetter = (string) => {
  return string?.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string?.slice(1);
}
    
    
    
    $: name = loggedInUserInfo?.name
    $: lastName = loggedInUserInfo?.lastName
</script>

<div style="display:flex; flex-direction: column;">
    <div>
        <span>Name: </span><input label="name" bind:value={name}>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Last Name: </span><input bind:value={lastName}>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

And this is `update` in `util` mimicking an API call:

```
export const update = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
            loggedInUserProfile.set({name: 'updated name', lastName: 'updated last name'})
        }, 1000)
}
```

If I change the `$` to `let`, the input will work, but I cannot have the updated value in the input. What is the solution here?

Comment: If you are going to have a separate save button there should not be much need to interact with the store directly, you can update local variables once when it is loaded, modify locally, then save back to the store on button click. You might want to elaborate on what exactly the workflow is supposed to be.

Comment: You're right, I updated this back to the original question, your comment on the response is descriptive enough for anyone if they have more confusions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should not use `subscribe` like that. For every manual `subscribe` you should call the returned function to unsubscribe. If you just want to get the value once outside a Svelte component, use `get` which can be imported from `'svelte/store'`.
2. Just bind directly to the store value via [`$` syntax](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-4-prefix-stores-with-$-to-access-their-values). You do not need any of the other script stuff. Using it like that the binding works both ways.

   ```html
   <input bind:value={$loggedInUserProfile.name} />
   <input bind:value={$loggedInUserProfile.lastName} />
   ```

Comment: I'm initializing loggedInUserProfile to null, and this will throw null exception before it gets initialized.

Comment: Also in my actual code I have something like $: name = computeSomFunction(loggedInUserInfo?.name), and I bind the resulted value to my input. not sure how I should handle that.

Comment: @AndishehKeikha I would not make the inputs available until the data is loaded, otherwise the user can make inputs which will then be overwritten anyway. So everything could be wrapped in `{#if}` displaying a skeleton UI or a spinner while `$loggedInUserProfile == null`. As for the transform, either apply it within the store or do not use `bind:` and instead pass the the transformed value into `value` and use `on:input` or the like to pass data back to the store (e.g. from `event.target.value`).

Comment: @AndishehKeikha Also, please ask questions that are actually representative of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you!!! Everything finally make sense now! Sorry, I am new to Svelte and it was hard for me to know which part of the code matters for this problem.